# Can't unlock bootloader for Lenovo a1000

Tags: rom-flashing

I have Lenovo a1000 which I need to flash.BIOS  isn't opening such that I could try wipe and reset,not even factory reset in settings is working....so I was left with none other option than flashing....but when I connect it to PC,instead of getting into flash mode,its charging...I guess my bootloader is probably locked....please suggest what's the problem and also ways tp tackle it.When I connect errors like code10,code 51,code 49.....etc. was shown individually....I thought the problem was in my PC but same problem occured in others too.

Comment: Flashing doesn't need unlocking the bootloader. You need drivers to make the device detected.

Answer (score 0):

According to your phone specs:

- Chipset **Spreadtrum SC7731**
- CPU Quad-core 1.3 GHz Cortex-A7

SPD devices don't have a flash mode that can be entered manually, but it is detected when you connect the powered off device to the computer (3 secs before it starts charging). They don't have recovery as well making hard reset impossible with button combo.

Open device manager (on Windows), Connect the device to the computer, you should notice something similar to SCI2COM... this is the flashing port, it last few seconds before the device starts charging.

You need a flash tool to flash ROM (.pac file or . bin). RechearchDownload is the official flash tool for Spreadtrum devices.

- Download ROM and flashtool for Lenovo A1000 SC7731 + extra drivers [here](http://firmwarefile.com/lenovo-a1000)
- Download SPD SCI drivers [here](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f723/spd-sci-android-usb-driver-jungo-v4-download-1611898/)
- To learn how to flash an SPD device, go [here](https://androidmtk.com/flash-pac-stock-rom-android-smartphone)