# E: can't mount/cache/recovery/log on Android Lenovo a1000

Tags: boot

I have a problem on starting my lenovo a1000 , so i decided to install firmware on it. I tried too much, but every time the phone fishing flashing , and 100% passed with spd factory flashing tool , but phone cant started.   I try already 5  flashable ROM, but same thing happens on every time. SO i decided to cheak its recovery, there i found 
E: Can't mount/cache/recovery/log 
... seeing on image for all error., now what can i do ? help please, Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP's account has been deleted, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

(Lenovo A1000 MTK MT8317 only) Next time, first make a full read back. flash only cache partition from SP Flash Tool.

If you don't have backup: install [platform_tools](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip), reboot to bootloader, connect phone, install drivers, open cmd.exe as Administrator, run `fastboot format:ext4 cache`

Comment: Thank You for replaying , but There is no scatter file for lenovo a1000 because of a spredtrum device, sp flash tool is for mtk devices, then how ? , However I flash only cache file with SPD research download tools, but the problem is same..

Comment: True, i have mixed up. Seems not all Lenovo are MTK. When fastboot formatting does not solve it, try booting twrp from fastboot. twrp has adb access, you can format cache manually with mke2fs

Comment: do not flash, try `fastboot boot TWRP-3.0.2.0__A1000__by__nemo-nemo.img` and in twrp `adb shell` and post output of `ls -l /dev/block/platform/*/by-name`
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=72839417&postcount=9

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166653

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache partition using **Recovery Menu**. After you open **Recovery Menu** (search methods online), navigate to **Wipe Cache Partition** using **Volume UP** and **Volume DOWN** buttons and then press **Power** button to select **Wipe Cache Partition**. Wait a while till it finishes wiping (if it doesn't fix the problem, try wiping again and flashing and fastboot, as said in other answers)

I'm having the same problem btw, I read this online but not sure if it works so let me know if it does!