# Tecno F1 stuck on boot animation how to fix it?

Tags: boot-loop

getting this error.
I'm trying to hard reset my Tecno F1 pro
[image]

Comment: Clicking through to the tag `boot-loop` you added opens to a number of similar questions with accepted answers. Did you try any and find them unsuccessful and in what way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: can't mount/cache/recovery/log on Android Lenovo a1000](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212853/e-cant-mount-cache-recovery-log-on-android-lenovo-a1000)